# Drop-down for job parameter in azure data bricks

Tags: azure, parameters, dropdown, databricks, jobs

Please help me with the query I Want to add drop-down for job parameter in azure data bricks job, I can do it at notebook level but couldn't at job level please help

Comment: can you please share the example for better understanding

Comment: Like similar to dbutils.widget.dropdown in notebook level, looking similar thing for job parameter